# Firebase query endAt() except/exclude its key

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

`FirebaseRef.orderByKey().endAt('c').limitToLast(2)` will return

`b, c`

I want to retreive except `c`, so `a, b` are what I want.

How can I do this?

Comment: There isn't an exclusive `endAt`, so retrieve 3 - not 2 - and discard the last.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to use `limitToFirst()` method like this:

```
FirebaseRef.orderByKey().limitToFirst(2);
```

You output will be: `a, b`

If you have data before `a`, you need to `startAt()` and `endAt` methods like this:

```
FirebaseRef.orderByKey().startAt('a').endAt('b');
```

Please see the official documentation regarding [Retrieving Data in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#range-queries)

Comment: sorry but that is not op way... I don't know key a

Comment: As i see in youe example, you know the keys. Otherwise you cannot achieve this.

Comment: Like @cartant comment, I discard the last item

Comment: Did my answer helped you in any way?

Answer (score 0):

If your `endAt()` query uses strings, it will compare lexicographically, so you'll need to subtract one charCode from the last character of the string. The following should work when searching for strings:

```
FirebaseRef.orderByKey().endAt(exclude('c')).limitToLast(2) will return


exclude(key){
    return key.substring(0, key.length - 1) + String.fromCharCode(key.charCodeAt(key.length - 1) - 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@godlerner's answer worked best for me however an edge case needs to be added because if you have a key that ends with a 0 it will replace the 0 with "/" which will cause the query to fail and throw an exception because firebase does not allow keys to contains "/"

This works better

```
exclude(key) {
  let unallowedChars = '.#$/[]'
  let newKey = key.substring(0, key.length - 1) + String.fromCharCode(key.charCodeAt(key.length - 1) - 1)

  if(unallowedChars.includes(newKey[newKey.length - 1])){
    while(unallowedChars.includes(newKey[newKey.length - 1])) {
      newKey = newKey.substring(0, newKey.length - 1) + String.fromCharCode(newKey.charCodeAt(newKey.length - 1) - 1)
    }
  }

  return newKey
}
```